# What files, file types, and folders to exclude from user folder backup?

Tags: backup, community-faq-proposed, crashplan

When backing up a user and shared users folder using the backup software of your choice on the operating system of your choice what files, file types, and folders do you exclude from the backup?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In [Java Regular Expression format](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Configuring/Excluding_Or_Filtering_Files_Using_File_Type_And_Regular_Expressions#External_Resources) (some data from [CrashPlan Excludes](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/What_Is_Not_Backing_Up#Admin_Excludes) and other unlisted excludes from CrashPlan's `my.service.xml` file):

All:

```
Default from CrashPlan: 
.*/(?:42|\d{8,}).*/(?:cp|~).*
(?i).*/CrashPlan.*/(?:cache|log|conf|manifest|upgrade)/.*
.*\.part
.*/iPhoto Library/iPod Photo Cache/.*
.*\.cprestoretmp.*
.*/Music/Subscription/.*
(?i).*/Google/Chrome/.*cache.*
(?i).*/Mozilla/Firefox/.*cache.*
.*/Google/Chrome/Safe Browsing.* 
.*/(cookies|permissions).sqllite(-.{3})?

Extra not in CrashPlan by default:
(?i).*\.(class|obj)
(?i).*\.(tmp|temp|cache|part|rbf|chk|dov) <-- temporary files
(?i).*\.(bac|bak|bkp|bup|back|dmp|dump|err|log|old|prv) <-- backup files
(?i).*\.(asd|wbk|xlk|bde|bdi|bdm|bmb|bom|crc|m\_p|bdb|bks|bps|mch|sol|idb|nch) <-- program specific backup/temporary files
(?i).*\.(bmk|chw|ftg|fts|gid|hhc|hhk) <-- help index files
(?i).*\.cache.*
:/Config\\.Msi.*
.*/Google/Chrome/.* <-- if using Chrome Sync
.*/Google/(Drive|CrashReports)/.*
(?i).*/(Google Drive|LocalGoogle)/.*
.*/Dropbox/.*
.*/.*SkyDrive.*/.*
.*/(My Cubby|cubby)/.*
(?i).*/Cookies/.*
(?i).*/Downloads/.*
(?i).*/.*cache.*/.*
(?i).*/.*log.*/.*
```

Windows:

```
Default from CrashPlan:
.:/ProgramData/
.*Thumbs\.db
.*/Local Settings/History/
.*/NetHood/
.*/PrintHood/
.*/Cookies/
.*/Recent/
.*/SendTo/
.*/LocalService/
.*/NetworkService/
.*/Start Menu/
(?i).*/NTUSER.*
(?i).:/WINDOWS/
(?i).:/autoexec.bat
.*\$RECYCLE\.BIN/.*
.*/System Volume Information/.*
.*/RECYCLER/.*
.*/I386.*
.*/pagefile.sys
.*/MSOCache.*
.*UsrClass\.dat\.LOG
.*UsrClass\.dat
.*/Temporary Internet Files/.*
(?i).*/ntuser.dat.*
.*/Local Settings/Temp.*
.*/AppData/Local/Temp.*
.*/AppData/Temp.*
.*/Windows/Temp.*
(?i).*/Microsoft.*/Windows/.*\.log
.*/Microsoft.*/Windows/Cookies.*
.*/Microsoft.*/RecoveryStore.*
(?i).:/Config\\.Msi.*
(?i).*\\.rbf
.*/Windows/Installer.*
.*/Application Data/Application Data.*
(?i).:/Config\.Msi.*
(?i).*\.rbf
(?i).*/Microsoft.*/Windows/.*\.edb 
(?i).*/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cookies(-journal)?
(?i).*/Safari/Library/Caches/.*
(?i).*/(Application Data|AppData)/Apple Computer/Mobile Sync/.*
.*\.tmp
.*\.tmp/.*

Extra not in CrashPlan by default:
.*/hiberfil.sys
.*/swapfile.sys
.*/Local Settings/History/.*
(?i).*\$RECYCLE\.BIN/.*
(?i).*/Windows/.*
.*/(Program Files|Program Files \(x86\))/.*
.*/AppData/Local/Packages/.* <- this really still needs to be figured out as per http://superuser.com/questions/490925/explain-windows-8-windows-store-appdata-packages-and-what-to-backup
.*/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows Store/.*
.*/NetHood/.*
.*/PrintHood/.*
.*/Cookies/.*
.*/Recent/.*
.*/SendTo/.*
.*/LocalService/.*
.*/NetworkService/.*
.*/AppData/LocalLow/.*
.*/Internet Explorer/.*
```

Mac:

```
Default from CrashPlan:
/bin/
/etc/
/sbin/
/usr/
/sw/
/System/
/private/
/dev/.*
.*\.Trash.*
/\.vol/.*
/mach.sym
/mach_kernel
.*\.hotfiles\.btree.*
.*/Trash/.*
.*/Network Trash Folder/.*
.*/VM Storage
.*\.fseventsd.*
.*/Library/Caches/.*
.*\.Spotlight-.*/.*
/Network/.*
/tmp/.*
/cores/.*
/afs/.*
/automount/.*
/private/Network/.*
/private/tmp/.*
/private/var/tmp/.*
/private/var/folders/.*
/private/var/run/.*
/private/var/spool/postfix/.*
/private/var/vm/.*
/Previous Systems.*
.*/lost\+found/.*
.*/Microsoft User Data/Entourage Temp/.*
.*/iP.* Software Updates/.*
.*/Library/Application Support/SyncServices/.*
.*/Library/Logs/.*
.*/Library/Mail/Envelope Index
.*/Library/Mail/AvailableFeeds/.*
.*/Library/Mirrors/.*
.*/Library/PubSub/Database/.*
.*/Library/PubSub/Downloads/.*
.*/Library/PubSub/Feeds/.*
.*/Library/Safari/Icons.db
.*/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db
.*/Library/Safari/HistoryIndex.sk
.*/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache
.*/iTunes/Album Artwork/Cache/.*
.*/iPhoto Library/iPod Photo Cache.*
(?i).*/backups.backupdb/.*
/Desktop DB
/Desktop DF
/Network/Servers.*
/Users/Shared/SC Info.*
/net/.*
/private/var/automount/.*
/private/var/db/dhcpclient/.*
/private/var/db/fseventsd/.*
/System/Library/Extensions/Caches/.*
.*Mobile.*Backups/.*
.*/Library/Saved Application State/.*
.*/Library/Mail/.*/Info.plist
.*/Library/Calendars/.*/Info.plist 
.*/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies(-journal)?
.*/Library/Cookies/(Cookies.binarycookies|com.apple.appstore.plist)
```

Linux:

```
Default from CrashPlan:
/bin/a
/boot/
/etc/
/initrd/
/lib/
/opt/
/sbin/
/usr/
/var/
/srv/
/sys/.*
/dev/.*
/proc/.*
/tmp/.*
.*/lost\+found/.*
/selinux/.* 
.*/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies(-journal)?

Extra not in CrashPlan by default:
(?i).*\~
```

Solaris:

```
Default from CrashPlan:
/bin/
/boot/
/etc/
/initrd/
/lib/
/opt/
/sbin/
/usr/
/var/
/srv/
/sys/.*
/dev/.*
/proc/.*
/tmp/.*
.*/lost\+found/.*
.*/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies(-journal)?
```

Comment: If any of my regular expressions can be simplified please fix them!

Comment: added some details from ehow.com/about_6565278_type-files-can-deleted_.html

Comment: this is certainly very useful, but I wonder if someone could comment on each line (or groups of similar lines) to explain what we're actually excluding here and why. - To give an example: I can see why it might make sense to exclude ProgramData completely. But I think it might also be a bit risky since it may well contain some (non-user-specific) application data, right? So some annotations might help people to customize the list for their purposes.

Comment: @Christoph, unfortunately,C:\ProgramData\ is excluded by Crashplan by default.  Guess what's in that folder?  This xml file! (I was adding regex's to the exclusion list and it erased ALL my custom Regex's.  With no backup from Crashplan.  Luckily I'm OCD engineer and I had it also backed up locally w/ Acronis True Image

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in this (2 years later). Under All, this entry `.*/(cookies|permissions).sqllite(-.{3})?` has two `l`'s (lower case `L`'s) in `.sqlite`

Answer (score 1):

Linux: Everything ending with a ~ (backups from several editors). And to "optimize" your regexps, just a short example:

```
(?i).*\.(tmp|temp|part|bak|\~)
```

Comment: Won't this result in searching for ".~" rather than "blahfile~"?

Comment: Ooops -- sure, you're right, that part I messed up. Intention was to shouw how to combine the regexps. But you're absolutely right: the `\~` part is wrong there and must go in a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

After careful examination I also exclude files **under %APPDATA%** that match (ignoring case) any of these regular expressions:

- Cache files

```
/Mozilla/.*/Cache
/MicrosoftEdge/Cache
/Chrome/.*/Cache
/Default/Media Cache
/GoogleEarth/unified_cache
/AppData/Local/Temp
/MicrosoftEdge/.*/Cache
/Skype/.*/emo_cache
/Device Metadata/dmrccache$
/cache$
/INetCache$
/LocalCache$
/Package Cache$
/WebCache$
/OfficeFileCache$
/CryptnetUrlCache$
/AppCache$
/IECompatCache$
/WebServiceCache$
/IECompatUaCache$
```

- log files

```
/logs$
/log$
```

- System files

```
/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows$
/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Device Stage$
```

- Temporary files

```
/temp$
/temporary[^/]*$
```

There's also discussion about this topic on https://forum.duplicati.com/t/common-exclusions-and-inclusions-from-appdata/807 . These lists appear there. **CAUTION** It seems like they use common regex but without taking care to escape literal dots):

```
.*/AppData/Local/Temp.*
.*/AppData/Temp.*

.*/AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\WPNPRMRY.tmp
.*/AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat.LOG1
.*/AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat.LOG2
.*/AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat
.*/AppData\Roaming\Skype\your.skypename\main.lock
.*/AppData\Local\Google\Drive\lockfile
.*/AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery\High\Active*.dat
.*/AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>.default\parent.lock
.*/AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Session
.*/AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Tabs
.*/AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\lockfile

*.part
*.tmp
*.ost
hiberfil.sys
pagefile.sys
swapfile.sys
*\UsrClass.dat*
*\ntuser.dat*
$Recycle.Bin\
Windows\
MSOCache\
*System Volume Information*\
*\AppData\*\Temp\
*\AppData\*\Internet Explorer\
*\AppData\*\Microsoft\*\WebCache\
*\AppData\*\Microsoft\*\INetCache*\
*\AppData\*\Microsoft\Office\*\OfficeFileCache\
*\Temporary Internet Files\
*\Firefox\Profiles\*\*cache*\
*\Microsoft\Windows Defender*\
```