# Backup Metro apps to install Later or on other PC's

Tags: backup, windows-8, modern-ui

I want to backup my current Windows 8 Metro apps so that I can install them to other PC's or Install them later if I format and re-install Windows 8 again.

I want to install these <strike>Metro</strike> Modern UI apps on a PC that does **NOT** have internet connectivity, I want an alternative way to install metro apps.

How can I do this?

Comment: You won't be able to transfer them as the applications are tied to your Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked a similar question on the Windows 8 Developer chat and [Jerry Nixon, Microsoft Developer Evangelist, gave me this answer](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17195?m=5698199#5698199) -

> There are two ways to install a Windows 8 app - either through the
> store or through side-loading. Side-loading has native support on Win
> RT, Win 8 Pro and Enterprise only. Windows 8 Core can be "enabled" by
> installing Visual Studio. As far as I know, apps from the store can
> not be copied and side-loaded to another PC. At least I hope not for
> IP sake.

[As per the Windows Store for developers blog, the two options available are](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305082627/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/04/25/deploying-metro-style-apps-to-businesses.aspx):

- Make the app available through the Windows Store, which means the app
  must adhere to the same certification policies and process required
  for all apps in the Store
- Build the app internally or sell it directly to the enterprise, which
  means IT admins must distribute the app directly to end-users within
  the enterprise, without involving the Store.

Going by these sources, installing a copy of a Windows 8 Metro app that you own, on multiple PCs doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 7):

The official way to reinstall Metro apps is to re-download them from the Store.

If you enter the store and right-click, you'll get the following menu:

[image: Store top menu]

If you then click on Your apps, you can see all the apps you have previously purchased or downloaded but which are not installed on the current PC:

[image: Apps not installed on this PC]

This gives you quick access to the app detail pages to start reinstalling.

Comment: I believe this is deliberately unsupported, as it would have no way to check you are authorised to install the app from the Store (especially for paid apps) - the only possible workaround is to contact the developer of a free app and ask if they would be willing to send the installation file to you for sideloading (how to sideload is another question entirely)

Comment: I guess, there would be some way to do the same thing as Chrome also installs Modern UI version of the same. Also when I am coding Modern UI apps, the resulting "Executable" file is a EXE but can not be launched simple by double-clicking. It needs to be launched by the Metro interface. The apps should be stored somewhere from where we can copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not supported yet.

However, I believe that will have to change because it causes a huge problem.
If people purchase and app in the store for $50 and then the developer for whatever reason pulls the app from the store. You are stuck without a way to ever install the product you paid for again.

That's a huge problem, the kind that leads to lawsuits.

I believe that policy will have to change at some point, once challenged.

Comment: Is hasn't happened to Apple yet, so I can't see it happening to Microsoft.