# Portable Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-8

Are there any portable Windows 8 Store Applications available? I want to install and run it on multiple Windows 8 devices without an internet connection, using portable devices (for example, a USB Stick).

Comment: How come this is not constructive? This is a "yes/no" question with a single definite answer - "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 apps can be run on more than one version of windows, if you sign in with the same account that bought/installed them.

If you want to transfer apps to another PC without an internet connection you can use **Windows Easy Transfer**, you can choose to transfer just settings, **just apps** or both.

Comment: If this isn't what you mean please let me know.

Comment: But it is not possible without internet connection..

Comment: Ahh ok, so you want to download the app, copy it to USB stick or something and install it from there?

Comment: See my edit, you can use Windows Easy Transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 Store Apps apparently [cannot be backed up or copied and side-loaded onto other PCs](https://superuser.com/questions/490948/backup-metro-apps-to-install-later-or-on-other-pcs). So for IP reasons you will only be allowed to re-install by downloading the app again from the Store. For the same reason I don't see how portable Store Apps will be possible, since they would go against this principle.