# Are Windows store applications device specific?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup Metro apps to install Later or on other PC’s](https://superuser.com/questions/490948/backup-metro-apps-to-install-later-or-on-other-pcs)

I was wondering if Windows store applications are device specific? So, if I change computers do I need to buy the applications again as is common in the Android Play Store?

Comment: @Karan not a duplicate as it asks about a senario commonly encountered marketplaces. Has nothing to do with backup, rather device change.

Comment: Yes, but read the answers there. Since Store apps can't be backed up, they need to be re-installed and the answers tell you how. Isn't that essentially what you have asked as well? If not, apologies, feel free to ignore.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify Matthew's answer, you can verify up to 5 computers with your Windows Live profile to sync purchases across your devices. This means that you need 1 application, per 5 devices, per Live ID.

From Windows [Store Terms of Use:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/store-terms-of-use)

> If you comply with these license terms, you have the rights below.
>
> INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS; EXPIRATION. You may install and use one
>   copy of the app on up to five (5) Windows 8 enabled devices that are
>   affiliated with the Microsoft account associated with your Windows
>   Store account.

Answer (score 1):

If you bought the app with your Windows Live ID then purchases can be synced throughout your devices.

Oh yeah and as Ethan mentioned its per 5 devices. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Does this means that I only need to buy 1 application? or 1 per device?

Comment: Just buying it once will suffice. As long as you use the same Windows Live ID for each of your devices.

Answer (score 1):

You have a limit of five devices per application license, but you must use the same Windows Live ID for each. Additionally, Windows Store applications are cross-platform as they are based on the WinRT runtime: they will run on both Windows 8 and Windows RT devices.